# Как переместить возвращаемое значение из JS на переменную PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Как отправить значение otvet на переменную php.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
 
var number_1 = $("#number_1").val();   
var number_2 = $("#number_2").val();   

otvet = number_1 + number_2;
$(".otvet > span").html(otvet);
 
});
```

Comment: Моя любимая ссылка http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: на какую переменную? что вы пытаетесь сделать? скорее всего вам нужен ajax

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы передать данные в PHP вам нужно совершить запрос на сервер через ajax.
На стороне сервера уже через глобальную переменную $_POST подставить полученные данные куда нужно